# Preventing image overflow in bootstrap grids

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Jumping back into html5 and css3 and using bootstrap for the first time (unfortunately I am not fully sure if we're using Bootstrap 4 or another version, please bear with me).

To make a footer on my site, I use a grid that can adjust to accomodate smaller screens. The footer is comprised of a grid that is only 3 columns (so it divides the footer into 3 equal parts, basically)
When my screen/footer width decreases below 850px, there's a problem with the first column.
The first column currently has 3 images in it, all logos. When the screen shrinks past width of 850px, the column overflows. The first 2 images are visible, but the third one (and the widest) overflows and goes below the first 2 images, no longer being visible. All images are the same height.

I don't want this to happen. I am trying to find a way to adjust the size of the images based on the width of a user's screen. It would be ideal if I could make these 3 images scale with the screen size, so as width decreases the images also get smaller.
Trying to see if there's a class, attribute, or selector to help me out in this situation. Otherwise, I am imagining that I'd have to reformat the footer to no longer use a grid format when the screen reaches a certain width and to simply line the images up with one another.

Thank you.

Edit: The grid column with the 3 images currently looks like this. I don't think CSS is worth including in here especially since there isn't much styling done except to alter image heights.

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <p class="text-center"> 
        <a href="http://dcc.dickinson.edu"><img id="DCC-logo" class="img-fluid" src="/static/images/DCC-logo.png"></img></a>
        <a href="http://www.cipl.ulg.ac.be/Lasla/"><img id="LASLA-logo" class="img-fluid" src="/static/images/LASLA-logo.png"></img></a>
        <a href="http://tdh.brynmawr.edu/"><img id="TriCoDH-logo" class="img-fluid" src="/static/images/TriCoDH-logo.png"></img></a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Share your code on something like codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: Added html to the  post itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create another grid structure for images inside the 3rd column `col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3` so that all the three images will be wrap in a row, and also add `img-responsive` class to all `img` tag to make them responsive.

Check the snippet below:

```css
@media (max-width:767px){
  .p5.col-xs-4{
    padding: 0 5px;
  }
  .m5.row{
    margin: 0 -5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="row text-center m5"> 
    <div class="col-xs-4 p5">
        <a href="http://dcc.dickinson.edu"><img id="DCC-logo" class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 p5">
        <a href="http://www.cipl.ulg.ac.be/Lasla/"><img id="LASLA-logo" class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 p5">
        <a href="http://tdh.brynmawr.edu/"><img id="TriCoDH-logo" class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually seems like the most valid solution... This is my first time working with Bootstrap so it just didn't ever cross my mind.

Since I am still getting used to Bootstrap, I'm going to look up some more info before I implement this (for instance, I don't know what 'p5' references in this context)

Comment: I have used `.p5` class here to give the `padding:0 5px` to the columns. We cant change the styling of bootstrap inbuild classes because these classes used everywhere so to prevent that I have used another class

Answer (score 0):

Make the image full width of the column you're using, so if you have a markup like

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      <img src="..."/>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      <img src="..."/>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      <img src="..."/>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can style the images as:

```
.row .col-md-4 img {
   max-width: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This would be useful if the footer was entirely made of those 3 images. It's true that my footer has 3 columns, but the three images are merely a part of one of those columns. So setting the image width to 100% doesn't seem useful (and at least from running my code... nothing happened)